# adding a forms to a html page with javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add a form with javascript and want to use this code:

```
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="afbeelding1" class="afbeelding">
    <form>
        <input type="checkbox" onclick="addOrRemoveSpecifications()">
    </form>
    <img src="afbeelding1.jpg">
</div>
</body>
<script>
function addOrRemoveSpecifications(){
    var div = document.getElementById("afbeelding1").firstchild;
    div.innerHTML=div.innerHTML + 
    '       
    <form>
        <select>
            <option value="320x200">320x200
            <option value="1024x768">1024x768
            <option value="1920x1200">1920x1200
        </select>
        <select>
            <option value="Canvas">Canvas
            <option value="Hout">Hout
            <option value="Digitaal">Digitaal
        </select>
    </form>
    ';
}
</script>
</html>
```

can anybody help me with this?

thank you in advance, you guys are awesome :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply use jquery or equivalent

```
myform = '<form ...';
$('afbeelding1').append(myform);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways depending what you want.

First Method

1.Add the form in your HTML itself where you want it.

2.Set the css :display of that form as none.

3.Use the JavaScript function to change the display from none to block.

```
function addOrRemoveSpecifications() { documentgetElementById("form").style.display="block"; }
```

Second Method:
Use the following to create your form :-

1.createElement

2.appendChild
.

For Example:http://jsfiddle.net/rvs4oq6p/